# have 3 divs to each other with spacers in between

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs that I want next to each other on my page. If the container is 700px in width, they all connect well. But I want to have a max width of 800px on my container. And in that case, I want all my divs to space out (1st div to the left, 2nd div in the center and 3rd div on the right). I need to connect those divs with 2 spacers that I've got (1 to connect div 1 and 2. The other to connect 2 and 3).

Once I have achieved that, I want a second div (content) to float above the first div (background). But I have already achieved that.

I have tried a few things, but I can't find a solution, if anyone could help me, I would appreciate it!

Here are my code snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #efefef;
  height: 800px;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: inherit;
}
.bg-left {
  height: 190px;
  width: 268px;
  background: url(images/left-1.png);
  float: left;
}
.bg-left-spacer {
  height: 190px;
  width: 1px;
  background: url(images/left-spacer.png);
  float: left;
}
.bg-connector {
  height: 190px;
  width: 133px;
  background: url(images/connector.png);
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg-right-spacer {
  height: 190px;
  min-width: 1px;
  background: url(images/right-spacer.png);
  float: left;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.bg-right {
  height: 190px;
  width: 297px;
  background: url(images/right-1.png);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
    <h1>testheader</h1>
    <p>testtext</p>
  </div>
  <div class='background'>
    <div class='bg-left'></div>
    <div class='bg-left-spacer'></div>
    <div class='bg-connector'></div>
    <div class='bg-right-spacer'></div>
    <div class='bg-right'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working? Seems fine to me if you edit the widhts. Or do you want it to be responsive?

Comment: Yes, if the container is 700px in width, it works fine. But I want the container to also work on 750, or 800 pixels. And I want to have it responsive for that.

Comment: Please share what you expect and what you are getting, maybe in form of mockups/screenshots?

Comment: I want my 3 divs to stay the same width. And to stretch out the spacers if there gets space in between my 3 divs. The left div should always stick to the left of the page. the center div should always stick in the center and the right div should always stick on the right.

Comment: @Max TRY THIS - http://jsfiddle.net/wy4ypa6w/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/q815uwu5/

Comment: Thankyou, that's how it needs to look, except I want a spacer in between to fill up the empty spaces between the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it like this:

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cthydjoz/)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 700px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #efefef;
    height: 800px;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
}
.background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.bg-left {
    height: 190px;
    width: 268px;
    background: url(images/left-1.png);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: table-cell;
}
.bg-connector {
    height: 190px;
    width: 133px;
    background: url(images/connector.png);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: table-cell;
}
.bg-right {
    height: 190px;
    width: 297px;
    background: url(images/right-1.png);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: table-cell;
}
.space {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
    background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='content'>
         <h1>testheader</h1>
         <p>testtext</p>
    </div>
    <div class='background'>
        <div class='bg-left'></div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div class='bg-connector'></div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div class='bg-right'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use percantages to achieve that:

```
.bg-left {
    height: 190px;
    width: calc( 100% / 3 - 1px );
    background: url(images/left-1.png);
}
```

This way `.bg-left` is 33.3% in width -1px for the spacer.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6aor5u4m/

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for. The 3 main divs need to have a fixed width, as they need to stay the same. The 2 spacers will fill up the space that gets in between the 3 divs when the width increases. http://jsfiddle.net/qgzv6umc/ This is a little example of how it should look in 800px.

Comment: @Max So do you want your spacers to be 1px in width or not? Can't see the relation between your answer and your demo, sorry.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, they need to have a min-width of 1, and can space as much as needed.